# Create JSON with column name and value as key-value pairs

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

We have to format a data export as JSON with a certain format. Here a test case:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (ID INT, value1 VARCHAR(30), value2 VARCHAR(30))
INSERT @tmp VALUES (1,'test1','test2')
```

Output should be:

```js
{
    "ID": 1,
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "value1",
            "value": "test1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "value2",
            "value": "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

We have to make two key-value pairs for some columns. The first describes the column name and the second the value. And on top pack it into an array.

I wonder if this is possible with native t-sql JSON functions, because I need a proper JSON as output (and not a string).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at `FOR JSON`? If not, I suggest doing so and then showing your attempt(s) if you fail.

Comment: [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) (Note: `FOR JSON` was added in SQL Server 2016. if you're using an older version of SQL Server, you will likely want to use something *else* to generate your JSON from the data (as doing so in T-SQL alone will not be a simply task), or create a CLR function. I have assumed you're using 2016+ in the absence of a version tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use nested `FOR JSON`:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(ID INT, value1 VARCHAR(30), value2 VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @tmp VALUES (1, 'test1', 'test2');

SELECT ID, custom_attributes = (
    SELECT attribute_code, value
    FROM @tmp AS x
    -- column to rows
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        ('value1', value1),
        ('value2', value2)
    ) AS a(attribute_code, value)
    WHERE x.ID = t.ID
    FOR JSON PATH
)
FROM @tmp AS t
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible answer, which works, but seems to be a bit complicated ...

```
SELECT tmp.ID
,      (
        SELECT ca.attribute_code
        ,      ca.[value]
        FROM @tmp tmp2
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES 
                ('value1',value1),
                ('value2',value2)
        ) ca (attribute_code, [value])
        WHERE tmp2.ID = tmp.ID
        FOR JSON PATH
        ) [custom_attributes]
FROM @tmp tmp
FOR JSON PATH
```